# Apex Test Execution Stuck in Queue

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I have attempting to run an Apex Test Execution and my test has been stuck in "Queue" since yesterday. It doesn't look as though I , as the Admin, have been locked but still no progress on the queue. I have selected "Abort", tried running the test in a different browser. I have also tried Clearing the test data, closing and then reopening the developer console.

I am still stuck in Queue. Has any one had this issue in the past? If so, how did you resolve it?

**update: 
Thank you everyone for your feedback.** It is nice to hear that we are not alone in this issue. Just as an update, I decided to skip the test step and go straight to deployment (yes, I know, shame on me). The deployment succeeded without the test (yay!) even though the test still looks as though it is still stuck in queue.

Moral of the story, reaching out to the masses has, at the very least, has given me peace of mind and I appreciate you all!

Comment: Over the last week I have noticed that test execution is stuck for over 24 hrs. Sometimes it actually runs, but most of the time it just never executed. I also saw that Sandbox creation (Dev) took 30 hours on another instance. This was all on CS instances and those nodes do not show any issues with salesforce. Shame there is no way for one to report it unless you pay for premier support. (And don't say email them cause we all know that is futile.) As for resolution, if you have premier support, open a case. Otherwise, just wait it out, abort the old requests and try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XgLAAU

> Summary Currently there is a suspension on all Apex test executions on
>   instances: 
>   - CS3 
>   - CS7 
>   - CS9 
>   - CS13 
>   - CS14

It affects browser UI, and dev console. I can still test via eclipse. I reported it to premier support and the CSR I spoke to said it has been going on since Friday. I hope they fix it soon.

Answer (score 1):

It's related to the release I'm sure. Even aborting the job as Tezyn does not resolve the root, as when you abort & re-run the tests they just hang again.

Comment: I am not disagreeing with you, but I am not sure I understand your answer either.  Are you saying that there is a known release issue preventing tests from executing or that there is something in the specific test that Jessica Ziegler reported and her release, preventing it from executing?  What makes this more than an isolated incident?

Comment: Just speculating based on my experience with the same problem & reports from others, it all seemed to start happening in the last week or so

Comment: At least on CS9, our resources say that R&D is researching the issue. We are not able to get through a full validate deployment for our release testing because the tests keep hanging (usually 1-3 out of every 150).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test this, but because the test runs are an instance of [AsyncApexJob](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm), you should be able to manage them using [System.abortJob(String job_id)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_abortJob).  Thanks to [JCD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575665/salesforce-how-to-cancel-queued-apex-future-jobs) for bringing my attention to this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in anonymous window and refresh the dev console. This will solve the problem:

```
List<ApexTestQueueItem> items = [SELECT Id, ApexClassId, Status, ExtendedStatus, ParentJobId FROM ApexTestQueueItem WHERE Status != 'Completed'];
for(ApexTestQueueItem atqi : items) {
    atqi.Status = 'ABORTED';
}
update items;
```