# Cloud not run test classes in sandbox

Tags: visualforce

Cloud not run test classes in sandbox and not getting error message when i run it.

```
@isTest(seealldata = True)
public class TestPropertyStatusTrigger  {

    Static TestMethod Void InsertnewAccounts() {
        account acc1 = createAccount('test1', 'New');
        update acc1;
        account acc2 = createAccount('test2', 'Cold');
        update acc2;
        contact con1 = createContact(acc1);
        contact con2 = createContact(acc2);
        campaign camp = createCampaign();
    }

    public static account createAccount(string str1, string str2) {
        account acc = new account(name = str1,
                                  Phone = '1234567890',
                                  site = 'Account site',
                                  Parcel_No__c = '1234',
                                  Property_Status__c = str2
                                 );
        insert acc;
        return acc;
    }

    public static contact createContact(account acc) {
        contact con = new contact(firstname = 'Test',
                                  lastName = 'Contact',
                                  accountid = acc.id);
        insert con;
        return con;
    }

    public static Campaign  createCampaign() {
        campaign camp = new campaign(name = 'Master Mailing List',
                                     IsActive = true);
        insert camp;
        return camp;
    }

    public static CampaignMember createCampaignMember(campaign comp, contact con) {
        CampaignMember compMemb = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = comp.Id,
                ContactId = con.id);
        insert compMemb;
        return compMemb;
    }
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: Actually it's not executing and not getting error message.

Comment: Is it this issue? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63728/apex-test-execution-stuck-in-queue/63753#63753

Comment: note also ... seealldata=true is not best practice and best to stamp it out with proper mock data setup before you get in too deep and run into deployment issues

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap your inserts into a try catch block.  Catch the DMLException then output it with an assert.  It is likely that you are missing a required field or some validation rule on the insert that is causing your issue.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer helped you solve your problem , please mark it as such, so other people can find and use it in the future.