# Apex tests stalling, nothing will run

Tags: apex, unit-test, sandbox

In sandbox, I have an issue getting any tests to run at all.  No matter what the test, or whether I start it from Apex Test Execution or the dev console, it stalls out in the 'Queue' status.  If I don't touch and come back hours later, it remains at that status.  At any time, I am usually able to abort the test, but there were a few times in which the test remained in the testing panel.  I am calling support for help soon, but just was checking for possible solutions, as I didn't get anywhere with any related questions' contents.  This has been ongoing for a few days now.

Comment: yes, i noticed this as well yesterday in one (but not all) of my sandbox orgs

Comment: That's right.  I have had no issues with other orgs.

Comment: Your problem seems to be related to the following question:
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63728/apex-test-execution-stuck-in-queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have been posted somewhere already, but Salesforce has acknowledged the issue of not being able to execute Apex tests in sandbox.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XgLAAU

Answer (score 0):

There is a governor limit on the number of test classes that you can queue up per 24-hour period: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm

Is it possible that you have been hitting the ol' test queue a little harder than usual today?

Comment: I was not aware of this, but unfortunately not.  Test numbers in the single digits, hardly anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue with a production validation deployment, ran my first 40 tests, and then stalled for roughly 15 minutes. Just started back up now... So, sometimes just wait for your instance to allocate test cycles may be the trick.